# Three component mixture model for element concentration using mixtools in R

Tags: r, gaussian-mixture-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

As an update to a previously posed question, [Fitting a mixture distribution for two approximately normally distributed populations using mixtools in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327372/fitting-a-mixture-distribution-for-two-approximately-normally-distributed-popula) , I have now fit a three component mixture distribution to a new variable.

The vector "Li" contains the values:
   0.000   0.000   0.030   0.030   0.040   0.040   0.070   0.070   0.070   0.070   0.080   0.080   0.080   0.080
    0.080   0.080   0.083   0.083   0.090   0.090   0.100   0.100   0.160   0.160   0.161   0.161   0.170   0.170
   0.190   0.190   0.190   0.190   0.200   0.200   0.260   0.260   0.300   0.300   0.320   0.320   0.328   0.328
    0.349   0.349   0.400   0.400   0.460   0.460   0.600   0.600   0.650   0.650   0.650   0.650   0.667   0.667
    0.700   0.700   0.820   0.820   0.880   0.880   0.900   0.900   0.950   0.950   0.990   0.990   1.100   1.100
    1.100   1.100   1.300   1.300   1.300   1.300   1.300   1.300   1.500   1.500   1.600   1.600   1.700   1.700
    1.700   1.700   1.800   1.800   1.800   1.800   1.800   1.800   1.800   1.800   1.800   1.800   1.900   1.900
    2.000   2.000   2.000   2.000   2.100   2.100   2.100   2.100   2.100   2.100   2.300   2.300   2.300   2.300
   2.400   2.400   2.400   2.400   2.400   2.400   2.400   2.400   2.500   2.500   2.500   2.500   2.600   2.600
   2.600   2.600   2.600   2.600   2.600   2.600   2.600   2.600   2.600   2.600   2.600   2.600   2.600   2.600
   2.600   2.600   2.600   2.600   2.700   2.700   2.700   2.700   2.700   2.700   2.800   2.800   2.800   2.800
  2.800   2.800   2.800   2.800   2.800   2.800   3.000   3.000   3.000   3.000   3.100   3.100   3.100   3.100
   3.200   3.200   3.600   3.600   3.800   3.800   4.000   4.000   4.000   4.000   4.000   4.000   6.200   6.200
   6.400   6.400   6.400   6.400   6.500   6.500   7.000   7.000   7.000   7.000   7.600   7.600   7.600   7.600
  10.000  10.000  10.000  10.000  20.000  20.000  29.000  29.000  29.000  29.000  30.000  30.000  30.000  30.000
  30.000  30.000  33.000  33.000  37.000  37.000  40.000  40.000  40.000  40.000  49.000  49.000  63.000  63.000
  64.000  64.000  65.000  65.000  67.000  67.000  76.000  76.000  90.000  90.000  93.000  93.000  95.000  95.000
 149.000 149.000 150.000 150.000 150.000 150.000 187.000 187.000 187.000 187.000 187.000 187.000 192.000 192.000
 195.000 195.000 210.000 210.000 215.000 215.000 219.000 219.000 220.000 220.000 224.000 224.000 229.000 229.000
 230.000 230.000 233.000 233.000 239.000 239.000 240.000 240.000 243.000 243.000 250.000 250.000 259.000 259.000
 260.000 260.000 270.000 270.000 270.000 270.000 287.000 287.000 290.000 290.000 300.000 300.000 300.000 300.000
 310.000 310.000 310.000 310.000 312.000 312.000 319.000 319.000 321.000 321.000 330.000 330.000 331.000 331.000
 391.000 391.000 398.000 398.000 425.000 425.000 444.000 444.000 600.000 600.000

This distribution is as follows:

[image]

I tried both a 2 & 3 component mixture model using mixtools in R.

2 component model:

[image]

3 component model:

[image]

The 3 component model looks like it is a better fit for the data. Would the k-s test be a good way to test the fit of each modal? I am aware of examples on this site of the k-s test being used to test the fit of a 2 component mixture, however I do not know how to alter the code to test the 3 component mixture.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use of the [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) or [BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) for checking the model fit? That's one of the ways you could find out how good the model is. Also, mixtools has a model selection implementation for mixture models, try that too.